# How to always display on the desktop?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi:
   I'm developing a software, now I want to create a tip like the time which always dispays on the desktop. Is there anyone could tell me how to do that?
   Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please just edit your question to provide more information, or use the comment facilities under the answers that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to create a [widget.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)